# Performing Multiple Correlation on Scarf Database

Tags: python, correlation

I am struggling with this database which you can see in the image below.
It is a database which contains some information about **scarves**.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wJis.png)

Here a brief description of the database:

- Drawing Code : is the identification code of each scarf model
- Q.ty : how many scarves were produced of that model
- Price : The unit price
- Final Price : is the multiplication between Q.ty and Price
- Drawing Class : identifies if there is a digital print on the scarf (1) or not (0)
- height & length : height and length of the scarf (measured in cm^2)
- Material : Material from which a scarf is made

Based on this data, I'm trying to predict the price of a scarf starting from the dataset I have, I also want to see which variables correlate with each other.

I chose some variables that in my opinion could influence the price of a scarf, and i put into a new dataframe:

`df1 = df[['Q.ty','Price', 'Area (cm^2)', 'Drawing Class', 'Material Class']]`

Performing **one-hot encoding** on the 'Drawing Class' and on 'Material Class' (because they are categorical variables) I tried to calculate, through a **heat map**, the correlation coefficients.

```
### heatmap

correlation_matrix = data1.corr()

#G.
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
sns.heatmap(correlation_matrix, annot=True, cmap='coolwarm', linewidths=0.5, fmt='.2f')
plt.title("Correlation Matrix Heatmap")
plt.show()
```

[heat-map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LssbM.png)

Unfortunately there is not a strong correlation between pairs of variables.
So I wonder: **Is it possible to calculate, on python, a multiple correlation index (with more than three variables)?**
**Also, is it right to look for a correlation between variables that are of different types?**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.